# Something happens because clause A, and clause B.

Tags: grammaticality

I wonder whether **because** can introduce two or even more reasons; if yes, how they are connected.

For example,

> John came late because he woke up late, and his bicycle was broken.

Is the sentence above correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: I'd prefer the verb "arrived" (or "showed up") to "came", but that's nitpicking and unrelated to the question of "because" (which is correct as it stands in the sentence).

Comment: Yes, it is grammatical. However, it's also ambiguous. It can mean either what you intend, or it can also mean that as a result of the facts that John woke up late and came late to school, his bicycle was broken.

Comment: @JohnLawler : Thanks. But how should I formulate the sentence so that it is not ambiguous and expresses what I intend?

Comment: Don't delete that second _because_: -- _because he woke up late, and **because** his bicycle was broken_. Most ambiguities come from deleting too many words; every time a word is deleted, information is lost from the signal, and must be reconstituted by the receiver, who has to guess. If there's not enough structure left to guide the guess, choices multiply rapidly.

Comment: @JohnLawler : Thanks for the correction. I am now writing a technical thesis and come across several such sentences. I am considering refining my ideas as two **because** in a sentence seems to be too much.

Comment: What @JohnLawler said.  An alternative (but not quite as clear) is to remove the comma. That shifts the scope of the *because* to the conjunction *he woke up late AND his bicycle was broken*.

Comment: @Drew Thanks! But is it not true that if **and** connects two full clauses(i.e., subject+verb), those clauses should be separated by comma?

Comment: @Drew : Sorry, I noticed that you already said, it is not quite as clear without comma.  What about such formulation? John came late. The reason is twofold. For one thing, he woke up late. For another, his bicycle was broken.

Comment: Generally, yes. But you can often omit commas if the sense is unambiguous (well understood). This is one reason I said that this is not quite as clear as repeating *because* (@JohnLawler's suggestion). Commas are there to help translate written text into something you might hear. They are pretty rough tools for that job, in general - all they do is indicate a pause in speech. Word order can often help understanding more than comma placement can. In this case, the simple addition of another *because* (@JohnLawler's suggestion) makes things quite clear.

Comment: Your multiple-sentence version is clear but choppy. That is the right way to start to express your ideas: short sentences. Often you will then want to smooth things out a bit by combining some of them. Combining also helps pull things together that are logically related. There is nothing wrong with using short, simple sentences, however.

Comment: @Drew : I see. Thanks. Maybe when the reasons are short, it's better to use two **because**s; when they are long, the multi-sentence version is better.

Comment: Alternatively, you could reframe the sentence as "John woke up late and his bicycle was broken, so he came late." That formulation also separates the two occurrences of "late" a bit more, which you may find desirable.

Comment: Yes, that comma is the irritant.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** yes, one "because" can introduce a list of reasons; no, your sentence does not say what you want to say because the comma separates "his bicycle was broken" from the list of reasons for John's lateness. The comma turns "his bicycle was broken" into an independent clause.

**Long answer:**

> John came late because he woke up late and his bicycle was broken.

without a comma is parsed like this:

> John came late because {{he woke up late} and {his bicycle was broken}}.

which means:

> John came late for the following two reasons. (1) He woke up late. (2) His bicycle was broken.

But with a comma:

> John came late because he woke up late, and his bicycle was broken.

it is parsed like this:

> {John came late because {he woke up late}}, and his bicycle was broken.

which means:

> John came in late because he woke up late. John's bicycle was broken.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest changing it to this (removing the Oxford/serial comma):

**John came late because he woke up late and his bicycle was broken.**

Removing the comma gives a flow that is less of a list and more of an overarching reason in combination.

Speaking of combination, you could change it to:

**John came late because he woke up late in combination with his bicycle being broken,(right of this comma, extend your list/reasons to greater than two, or simply add a period/full stop)**